# How to create a folder based on date using Data Factory?

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-factory

I'm using data factory and I've an activity which copies data from one location to the other. However I'd like the destination location to be like 'container/Year/Month/Day' where year, month, and day are automatically generated. The source and destination address are given to my job as parameters so they should be in the argument part of the activity. I'm stuck and don't know how to specify them

Comment: How do you pass arguments to the activity? there's no argument section to an activity in a pipeline....

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a straight Copy Activity, then you can specify the Blob folder path in the same way you do for an input file:

```
{
  "name": "AzureBlobOutput",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "StorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
      "folderPath": "mycontainer/myfolder/yearno={Year}/monthno={Month}/dayno={Day}/hourno={Hour}/",
      "partitionedBy": [
        {
          "name": "Year",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "yyyy"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Month",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%M"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Day",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%d"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Hour",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%H"
          }
        }
      ],
      "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat",
        "columnDelimiter": "\t",
        "rowDelimiter": "\n"
      }
    },
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Hour",
      "interval": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from the sample docs here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/

If you are using a Custom .NET Activity then you need to pass your parameters as part of the extendedProperties within the typeProperties JSON section:

```js
"typeProperties": {
          "AssemblyName": "MyDotNetActivity.dll",
          "EntryPoint": "MyDotNetActivityNS.MyDotNetActivity",
          "PackageLinkedService": "StorageLinkedService",
          "PackageFile": "customactivitycontainer/MyDotNetActivity.zip",
          "extendedProperties": {
            "SliceStart": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyyMMddHH-mm}', Time.AddMinutes(SliceStart, 0))"
          }
        },
```

and then read the extendedProperties metadata in your C# class as shown here:

```cs
public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(
    IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices,
    IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets,
    Activity activity,
    IActivityLogger logger)
{
    // to get extended properties (for example: SliceStart)
    DotNetActivity dotNetActivity = (DotNetActivity)activity.TypeProperties;
    string sliceStartString = dotNetActivity.ExtendedProperties["SliceStart"];

    // to log all extended properties           
    IDictionary<string, string> extendedProperties = dotNetActivity.ExtendedProperties;
    logger.Write("Logging extended properties if any...");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in extendedProperties)
    {
        logger.Write("<key:{0}> <value:{1}>", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
    ....
```

Taken from the sample docs here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/